# Dropbox: I can only view old files

Tags: dropbox

I can no longer view new files in Dropbox on my Android phone. On investigation, I find that it says Offline. How do I change the settings to see all the files online?

Comment: Try logging out then back in. Is Syncing activated?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but see the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

In desperation, I went to Settings then Connect a Computer and went through the routine of installing Dropbox on my desktop (in spite of it being there already). The installation took much longer than the original, but all files are appearing on the Android devices which I use.

Not very intuitive...